# xmlnodelist to dropdown

Tags: xml, html-select

I am trying to generate a list(of string) to use as a datasource for a dropdown list.
I have done this numerous times but this version is not separating the items out as it normally does.

Here is an xml sample

```
<fueltypes>
<fuel>
  <type>Marine Diesel NY Harbor</type>
  <dbheader>NYMarineDiesel</dbheader>
</fuel>
<fuel>
  <type>ULSD NY Harbor</type>
  <dbheader>NYULSD</dbheader>
</fuel>
</fueltypes>
```

Here is the function

```
Public Shared Function GetFuelTypes(ddlControl As Control) As List(Of String)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

    'Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
    doc.Load("H:\OtherDataFiles\dataXML.xml") 'this needs to be changed to the server path
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement

    'Select all nodes with the tag paramter indicated by the nodestring variable
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("fueltypes")
    Return (From node As XmlNode In nodeList Select node.InnerText).ToList()
End Function
```

They get bound to the dropdown as follows

```
 'load the fuel types into the dropdownlist
    ddlFuelTypes.DataSource = GetFuelTypes()
    ddlFuelTypes.DataBind()
    ddlFuelTypes.SelectedIndex = 1
```

The dropdown displays all the items in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either fully qualify `nodeList`, so that you get to the sub-elements that contain the text you want, e.g.

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/fueltypes/fuel/type")
```

Or, you need to loop through `nodeList` and read the elements you need, e.g.

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/fueltypes/fuel")

For Each fuelNode In nodeList
    Dim fuelType = fuelNode.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
```

Comment: Note: the / at the front of the string /fueltypes/fuel/type is not needed, and causes an error, in the code line  Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/fueltypes/fuel/type")